# How can I solve this dependency problem in sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

I am new to Scala, I am learning it. I tried to add a dependency in my SBT, but it can not resolve the dependency.

The code of **build.sbt** is here.

```
name:="scalaTest"
version:="0.1"

librarydependencies := "com.github.mmnu" %% "scalafh" % "0.1-SNAPSHOT"
```

Comment: What error are you getting? - BTW, I am not sure if it was a problem with the copy-paste but it should be the **ASCII** percentage character _(`%`)_.

Comment: it can not resolve the dependency

Comment: Still does not indicate the error (can hardly expect to get helped)

Comment: I gave it a quick google and maven search, i can not find that dependency / project anywhere. Are you sure it at least exists? - Maybe it is an internal dependency in your office?

Comment: The error is here- 
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.github.mmnu#scalafh_2.13;0.1-SNAPSHOT: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is happening because SBT is not getting module in both local repository and maven repository.As your module is a `SNAPSHOT` it will not be released to maven. So you will have to tell the SBT that where the module actually exists. It is done by resolver. Add this in your SBT

```
resolvers += "Sonatype OSS Snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
```